# What's the Java2D Disposer Thread?

Tags: java

I have created a sample java application working with Hibernate, when I doing the thread-dump I observe the strange thread called Java2D Disposer.

Can someone tell me the function of that thread?

Answer (score 15):

Certain entities in the AWT system need finalization to free resources. The most prominent example is `java.awt.Windows` which needs to dispose its native resources after the window is garbage collected.

One could do this with finalizers, but a solution that gives you more detailed control is to use phantom references with a reference queue. That solution needs a dedicated thread which waits on the reference queue. That thread is the "Java 2D disposer" thread, It is created when you initialize the AWT system.

Comment: Clean answer! Could you explain me what are those native resources and why should they be disposed?

Comment: we saw this thread in our thread dumps of our web service which does NO UI work at all. is there a way to stop creating this thread? or should we not worry about this at all?