# Java2D Disposer Thread crashing the JVM

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, jvm-crash

My application is running on a jboss which randomly crashes. After generating the below error file, we started investigating.
We are running with the following ecosystem:

- jboss : JBOSS EAP 6.2
- jvm : 1.7.0.121-2.6.8.1.el6_8
- OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
- uname:Linux 2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64
- libc:glibc 2.12

If I well understood, this is due to the garbage collection of native resources created by java.awt package. The thread responsible of that is  Java2D Disposer. [What's the Java2D Disposer Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897420/whats-the-java2d-disposer-thread)

The JVM seems to crash because of an internal bug :

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7103530

I have some questions:

1. How can I have access to the ticket 6953445 mentioned in JDK-7103530 above?
2. Can someone confirm I well understood the problem and there
   is nothing I can do in my application to fix the problem?
3. Is there a solution to this problem?

Below the head part of the error file:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
     
       SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003be4a75f05, pid=39931, tid=140659847448320
     
      JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_121) (build 1.7.0_121-mockbuild_2016_11_01_00_38-b00)
      Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.121-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
        : IcedTea 2.6.8
      Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago), package rhel-2.6.8.1.el6_8-x86_64 u121-b00
      Problematic frame:
      C  [libc.so.6+0x75f05]
     
      Core dump written. Default location: ------- or ----
     
      If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
      instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
        http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
      The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
      See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
     
    
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
    
    Current thread (0x00007fed5c0e5000):  JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=40219, stack(0x00007fedec2dc000,0x00007fedec3dd000)]
    
    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Oracle created a new bug system, but the #6953445  is unavailable... https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7103530

Comment: Did you find anything about that problem? I might have the same...

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate of 6953445.
User deleting temp files being actively used by the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

In our context, the bug was due to pdfbox library.
See more details here https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1336

Updating the library solved the problem.